# how to replace a string and there is a variable inside it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

`$string = "bla bla assset('https://img1') bla bla assset('https://img2') etc....";`

I was trying to replace every `assset('https://img')` to `<img src="https://img1">`

Comment: Why not simply use str_replace or preg_replace for advanced replacement?

Comment: Is the `1` always added or number should come from the `img` in the haystack?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions for that.

```
$string = "bla bla asset('https://img1') bla bla asset('https://img2') etc....";
$html = preg_replace("/asset\('(.*?)'\)/", '<img src="$1">', $string);
```

Output of `echo $html;`

```
bla bla <img src="https://img1"> bla bla <img src="https://img2"> etc....
```